# Scrape text after every <br> - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape this URL
http://deals.whotels.com/W-Guangzhou-3126/tnc/1680/24900/en
I have to get each and every *Terms & Conditions*
I have got the HTML markup in `test`

```
test = terms_and_conditions_soup.select(".popBodyText")[0]
for tes in test.findAll('br'):
    print(tes.extract())
```

But this only prints `<br>`s.

I can get all the terms like `terms_and_conditions_soup.select(".popBodyText p")[0].text` but I don't want like that.

Even I see no logic to scrape those Terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms and conditions are simply lines of text delimited by `<br>` breaks. You can get all the text with newlines in between with the [`.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
terms_elements = terms_and_conditions_soup.select(".popBodyText")[0]
terms = terms_elements.get_text('\n', strip=True)
```

or you could loop over the [`.strings` or `.stripped_strings` generators](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
terms = list(terms_elements.stripped_strings)
```

If you only wanted the bulleted lines, select for those:

```
terms = [t.lstrip('\u2022 ') for t in terms_elements.stripped_strings
         if t.startswith('\u2022')]
```

I removed the bullet from the selected lines too.

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://deals.whotels.com/W-Guangzhou-3126/tnc/1680/24900/en').content)
>>> terms_elements = soup.find(class_='popBodyText')
>>> [t.lstrip('\u2022 ') for t in terms_elements.stripped_strings if t.startswith('\u2022')]
['Offer valid at W Guangzhou only.', 'Offer is valid for stays booked by December 30, 2014 and stays completed from December 30, 2014 to January 1, 2015.', 'Limited number of rooms available.', 'Minimum stay of 2 nights is required & must stay over December 31, 2014.', '15% service charge and tax is not included in the package and subject to change without any notice.', 'Breakfast to be consumed at the Kitchen Table restaurant on departure day. Guest will be eligible for the breakfast based on number of persons booked overnight. Additional persons will be charged at the restaurant according to retail price.', 'NYE dinner buffet to be consumed at The Kitchen Table on December 31, 2014 only. Two guests per room will be eligible for the dinner buffet, and additional guests will be charged at the restaurant according to retail price. Prior reservations for the additional guests are required.', 'Free access to the FEI NYEcountdown party on December 31, 2014 is limited to a maximum of 2 adults only per room. Guests under 18 years old will not be allowed. The tickets will not be sold to general public or any external guests. Please collect the passes at time of check in.', 'Alcoholic beverage service is restricted to those 18 years or older (with valid identification).', 'Massage treatment in the package is limited to 60min AWAY Spa Signature Massage only. Spa treatment cannot be cumulated & valid during stay only. Prior reservation is recommended for the Spa treatment. This is to ensure space availability and the hotel will not be held responsible for any unconsumed portion of the package.', 'All package components are not transferable and must be consumed during stay. If any portion is not consumed, they will not be refundable or exchangeable in cash.', 'Extra services & amenities not part of the package will be charged per consumption & will be on guest’s own expense.', 'All package amenities are per room/per night and will be presented upon arrival unless otherwise noted.', 'This offer is only available if booked via Starwood distribution channels. Offer will not be applicable if booked through third party distribution channels, travel agents or any other external websites.', 'Offer not applicable to groups nor is it combinable with other special/discounted rates.', 'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Worldwide, Inc. reserves the right to cancel this promotion at anytime without notice.', 'Not responsible for omissions or typographical errors. Void where prohibited by law. Not to be combined with offers or promotions.', 'Any unused portion/s of the package is not transferable or exchangeable for cash/credit.', 'Starpoints, SPG, Starwood Preferred Guest, Sheraton, Four Points, W, Aloft, Le Meridien, The Luxury Collection, Element, Westin, St. Regis and their respective logos are the trademarks of Starwood Hotels & Resorts Worldwide, Inc., or its affiliates.']
```

Comment: I wanted to iterate over all the bullets.

`for terms in terms_elements.strings: print(terms.lstrip('\u2022'))`

This is all I wanted ... and many many thanks to you sir...